# mongodb-Limiting Embedded item when insert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to design a schema where post will not able to contain more
than 10 tags.

How could i achieve that?

Any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/b07397a005de86ed

Comment: The gist is that you can include a counter field for the embedded array, and limit updates to documents where the counter <10: db.collection.update({_id: 1, counter : {$lt : 10}, tags: {$ne: 
newTag}}, {$inc : {counter: 1}, $push : {tags: newTag}})